# AngularJS Counting Number of Specific Nodes in JSON Dataset

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I have a set of JSON data:

```
"MyMessages": [
        {
            "Code" :  "N101",
            "ID" : "History",
            "Indicator" : "Down",
            "PosChangeMessage" : "test test test test",
            "NegReasonMessage" : "test test test test",
            "Image" : "ImageType.Warning"
        },

        {
            "Code" :  "A874",
            "ID" : "History",
            "Indicator" : "Up",
            "NegReasonMessage" : "test test test test",
            "Image" : "ImageType.Ok"
        },

        {
            "Code" :  "X85",
            "ID" : "Age",
            "Indicator" : "Down",
            "PosChangeMessage" : "test test test test",
            "Image" : "ImageType.Warning"
        },

        {
            "Code" :  "Z846",
            "ID" : "Products",
            "Indicator" : "Up",
            "PosChangeMessage" : "test test test test",
            "Image" : "ImageType.Ok"
        },
    ],
```

I can display how many items there are in MyMessages via `{{ MyMessages.length }}`

However what i want to know is how many `PosChangeMessage` and how many `NegChangeMessage` items there are.

So, in the example above:

PosChangeMessage = 3

NegChangeMessage = 2

Comment: There is no syntactic sugar to help you here. So you'll have to count the values in some way or the other. E.g. (filter, controller-methods, $watch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see here : http://jsbin.com/yaxiya/1/

```
 angular.forEach(MyMessages, function(message){

       if(message.PosChangeMessage){
       $scope.PosChangeMessage++;
       }
       if(message.NegReasonMessage)
       {
       $scope.NegChangeMessage++;
       }


       });
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a method in the controller which iterates over the length of "MyMessages" and calculate the corresponding values, like this in your controller..

```
for(var i=0;i<MyMessages.length;i++){
  if(MyMessages[i].PosChangeMessage!=null){
    $scope.posChangeMessageLength++;  
  }
  if(MyMessages[i].NegReasonMessage!=null){
    $scope.negReasonMessageLength++;  
  }

}
```